# UIPageViewController Swipe Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

My iOS app is using a UIPageViewcontroller with about 18 pages. Each page has a UITableView in it with 4 dynamic cells. Each cell has about 10 different images.

The problem is that each time I swipe the UIPageViewcontroller to go to the next/previous page, there's like a half-second delay that makes the user experience pretty bad.

It seems like the UITableView of the next page to be displayed after the swipe is loading all its heavy-data cells and that originates this delay.

I've read it's possible to make this loading asyncronous but I have no idea about how to do this.

**Any of you guys have any idea about how to avoid this delay so the transition to pages runs smoothly?**

Here's some code for the UITableView:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cellsStatus[indexPath.row] integerValue] == CLOSED_CELL)
        return [GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell getHeightForCell];
    else
        return [GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell getFullHeightForCell];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([mainController respondsToSelector:@selector(tableViewDidScroll:)] &&
        [mainController isKindOfClass:[GrintScoreTrackViewController class]])
    {
        [mainController tableViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;
    GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell *cell, *cellOwner;

    // Cell ID
    CellIdentifier = @"GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell-ID";

    // Creating the cell
    cell = (GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Creating the cell owner
    cellOwner = [[GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Getting cell from Nib, if possible.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell" owner:cellOwner options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Filling cell with the corresponding user info
    [cell fillCellWithContent];

    // Changing appearance based on the new status
    [self setStatusOfCell:cell withStatus:[cellsStatus[indexPath.row] integerValue]];

    // Setting action for cell's "collapseButton" button
    [cell.collapseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCellStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Setting action for cell's "editScoresButton" button
    [cell.editScoresButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editScoresButtonWasPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Setting action for cell's "pickerEnterButton" button
    [cell.pickerEnterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerEnterButtonWasPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Setting cell selection style
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    // Setting picker view delegate and data source.
    [cell.pickerView setDelegate:self];
    [cell.pickerView setDataSource:self];

    return cell;
}
```

And some code from the **GrintScoreTrackPlayerDynamicCell** cell:

```
- (void) fillCellWithContent
{
    // Doing some processing fixes
    [self postProcessCellContent];
}

- (void) postProcessCellContent
{
    CGSize textSize;
    CGFloat scoreLabelTextWidth, newHazzardLabelXValue, newPuttsLabelXValue, offset;

    // Setting an offset for the hazzard and putts label. This offset represents the distance between the score label text and the hazzard and putts labels.
    offset = 1;

    // Getting the width of the text that's inside the Score Label.
    textSize = [[self.scoreLabel text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[self.scoreLabel font]}];
    scoreLabelTextWidth = textSize.width;

    // Getting new x position value for the Hazzards Label.
    newHazzardLabelXValue = self.scoreLabel.frame.origin.x +
                            (self.scoreLabel.frame.size.width - scoreLabelTextWidth) * 0.5 -
                            self.hazardsLabel.frame.size.width - offset;

    // Setting the new x position value for the Hazzards label
    [GrintUtils moveView:self.hazardsLabel inX:newHazzardLabelXValue andY:self.hazardsLabel.frame.origin.y];

    // Getting new x position value for the Putts Label.
    newPuttsLabelXValue = self.scoreLabel.frame.origin.x +
                         (self.scoreLabel.frame.size.width - scoreLabelTextWidth) * 0.5 +
                          scoreLabelTextWidth + offset;

    // Setting the new x position value for the Putts label
    [GrintUtils moveView:self.puttsLabel inX:newPuttsLabelXValue andY:self.puttsLabel.frame.origin.y];
}
```

Here's some code about my UIPageViewController with the pages pre-loaded in **pageContent** array:

```
#pragma mark - UIPageViewController Data Course

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Getting the previous of the next controller
    int index;
    index = currentPageBeingDisplayed - 1;
    if (index < 0)
        index = [pageContent count] - 1;

    return pageContent[index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Getting the index of the next controller
    int index;
    index = currentPageBeingDisplayed + 1;
    index = index % [pageContent count];

    return pageContent[index];
}
```

A screenshot of Instruments Tool **Counter** focused on the delay:

[image]

An finally 2 pictures (it has 2 states) of the cell:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to show your `fillCellWithContent` method.  The other thing you should do is pre-load the "next" view controller in your `pageViewController` - that way it will probably have loaded all of its data before it is displayed.  Also fetching the data in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not ideal - you should pre-fetch the data in `viewDidLoad` or similar

Comment: And use Instruments! It will tell you exactly where that "delay" is being spent.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 , I just editted the code to add the fillCellWithContent method... On the other hand, I have preloaded all the pages of my UIPageViewController in and array. So I create them just once. I just added some code about it too... I don't get any data from a server yet. Everything is local.

Comment: Ok, if you aren't getting anything from a server then asynchronous won't help you.  As matt suggested use Instruments to see where time is spent

Comment: Hey @matt , I just added a screenshot of Instruments focused on the delay. Could you please help me by targeting the place where the delay occurs. I know nothing about Instruments to be honest.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 , I just added a screenshot of Instruments focused on the delay. Could you please help me by targeting the place where the delay occurs. I know nothing about Instruments to be honest.

Thank you :)

Comment: OK, I realized it's because all the image that are in each cell. In the .xib file I made for these cells, there're about 20 images. I removed them and It runs smoothly... Please guys, any idea about how to improve the performance of these cells? Thanks @Paulw11

Comment: @jmoukel Are you kidding? You are doing great without any help at all! Excellent detective work. Well done. - So, just to be clear, how do these images get into the cell? I don't see any code that does that; are you saying it happens because the images are in the cell-defining .xib?

Comment: @matt lol... Thanks man :) ... Yes, the images get into the cell through the .xib I defined for those cells. I mean, I defined the cells' UI by using the Interface Builder, not by code.

Comment: @jmoukel That's enough info for me to make a suggestion - see my answer below. Might not work, but I think it will! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a wild guess - I haven't tried it. But from what you've so brilliantly deduced, and from what you've said in your comments, I take it that this is how the images get into the cells: they are in the cell-defining *.xib*.

So, for every row of the table, the *.xib* is loaded and the images must all be loaded freshly from the *.xib*. This is what we believe is slowing you down.

So here's a suggestion: don't do that. Instead, just have empty image views in the cell, and populate them with images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Why would this help? Because if you fetch an image by calling `imageNamed:`, the image is *cached by the system*. Thus each image will be fetched once and will be cached forever after.

One more suggestion - make sure the images are *small*, i.e. the same size as they will be displayed. It is a huge waste of time to start with a large image and display it in a small image view, because the version of the image to be displayed must be *calculated* every single time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Matt! .... However, I made a mistake. Those 20 or more images I told you about were just UIViews with color backgrounds that I rounded. There're only 3 images in each cell. I already resized them so they are smaller and now I load them in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method (instead of the .xib file). But the problem persists, the transition is still laggy... So, don't you think this delay is because those 20 or more UIViews are being rendered? I added a pic of the cell (in the initial post) so you can see how many view it has. Thanks!

Comment: Rounding by manipulating a CALayer can certainly stress out the rendering tree. Again you just need to experiment. Take out the "rounding" code and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I did try removing the rounding but the problem persists... Also, each cell also has its own UIPickerView (I added another pic in the post). But after removing the UIPickerView, it gest just a little better the laggy problem persists.

Comment: Okay but you keep moving the goal posts. You said you solved the lag by changing something. Well, that was it. So what was it?

Comment: Yes, after removing all the views below the Label T. Woods (including the UIPickerView) the lag just disappears. But I need to have those views in my cells.

Comment: "But I need to have those views in my cells" Why? If they are not visible when the cell appears (because the cell is in the other state), why do you need them initially? If they are the problem, get rid of them and don't use them until the user switches states.

Comment: Ohhh... So you mean I should create those views when the user switches to the state that uses those views?

Comment: If it helps the initial swipe, do whatever you have to!

Comment: OK, I'll try that and let you know... Thank you SO MUCH :)

Comment: Not until we see if it helps! And even then, you are the one doing all the work. It's like being Sherlock Holmes; you just have to keep narrowing it down...

Comment: Hey Matt, just wanted to let you know that your suggestions worked out pretty well.

Comment: What I did was to add the heavy-weight views only when the user wants to expand a cell. And when this happens, if there's another cell expanded, I collapse it and just leave the last one selected expanded... I wish I could accept one of your comments as the correct answer... Thanks a lot though. You helped me tons. I was stuck for 2 weeks. Have a good day :)

Comment: It's great that you worked something out! You can answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can accept your own answer). It's good form, and it helps others.